# Node.JS: Javascript classes VS no classes in REST API

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, javascript-objects

I am developing a REST API using Node.JS and AWS Lambda, which will be accessed by 3 apps.

1. Android app developed with Flutter
2. iOS app developed with Flutter
3. Web app developed with Java

I have always been a `Java` guy and never a `Javascript` guy. This is my first time on serious job with Javascript stuff.

Normally when we create REST APIs in Java, it will get the data from the database, convert it to a Java class and send it back as the `response`.

For an example, lets assume below is the structure of my database table. Have a close look at the names, AND the associated `foreign keys`.

[image]

In my Java based REST API, this will be the class.

```
public class SellerSettings  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idsellerSettings;
     private User user;
     private double responseRate;
     private double responseTime;
     private boolean isavailable;

    public SellerSettings() {
    }

   
    public Integer getIdsellerSettings() {
        return this.idsellerSettings;
    }
    
    public void setIdsellerSettings(Integer idsellerSettings) {
        this.idsellerSettings = idsellerSettings;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
    
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public double getResponseRate() {
        return this.responseRate;
    }
    
    public void setResponseRate(double responseRate) {
        this.responseRate = responseRate;
    }
    public double getResponseTime() {
        return this.responseTime;
    }
    
    public void setResponseTime(double responseTime) {
        this.responseTime = responseTime;
    }
    public boolean getIsavailable() {
        return this.isavailable;
    }
    
    public void setIsavailable(boolean isavailable) {
        this.isavailable = isavailable;
    }
}
```

When the data is requested from an API built with Java, it will send the response back with the same set of names you see in the `java` class I presented. Since the `user` is another class, it will actually add that's fields as well..

Anyway, this is my node.js code now.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : "*******.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user     : "****",
  password : "*****",
  port     : 3306,
  database : "*****"
});

exports.lambdahandler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const sql = "select * from seller_settings";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
  
      var response = {
          "statusCode": 200,
          "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": JSON.stringify(result),
          "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response)
    });
  };
```

And it return the below

```
[
    {
        "idseller_settings": 1,
        "iduser": 1,
        "response_rate": 90,
        "response_time": 200,
        "isavailable": 0
    },
    {
        "idseller_settings": 2,
        "iduser": 1,
        "response_rate": null,
        "response_time": 210,
        "isavailable": 0
    }
]
```

It is nothing but the pure table names.

As a Java guy, I looked at how we can convert these to the Java like names. Then I found `Javascript classes`. However I do understand that Javascript is not OOP as `Java` or anything similar. It is not perfect on OOP. Also adding these class, converting the values from JSON to classes, and the sending it back seems to be an over kill for my simple, nice Node.JS code.

As a Java guy, I would ask,

1. When requested via the REST API, Is it normal to grab the data from the database tables as per column names as it is and send it back in Javascript world? Or should I create classes?
2. My mobile and web apps are using `classes` in their languages, when sending `POST`  requests they will most probably send a JSON that contains `Java` classe's variables I shared. From the node.js side, this can be converted to table names?

Comment: RE point 1, my approach is to use the column headings where possible, provided they’re not too abstract. I had a few projects where I changed them before passing the data back to the app and it felt like unnecessary extra work and an additional source of possible errors. Better to keep everything consistent.

Comment: @MattSaunders: Thanks Matt. What about the second point? Apps will have different variable names anyway....

Comment: However I’ve started using Typescript rather than JavaScript for my Node apps, which allows you to assign expected types to your database responses. So this might be worth considering as an alternative to give your data some “shape”. Probably wouldn’t go back to plain JS at this point

Comment: so in your apps, you have dealt with `table names` coming from your API and inside the apps you converted them into correct objects? When the apps sending `POST` requests, they sent objects and the API converted them back to `table names`?

Comment: RE the second point, I’m probably not most qualified to comment! If some conversions have to happen (which sounds like it’s the case?) I’d try to keep it as clean and consistent as possible. So maybe your Node app is the best place for this?

Comment: Not sure. Because in Java, Flutter and other languages the JSON to object mapping is easy. Thats what I am thinking of..

Comment: To be honest I really liked the question and just wanted to show it a bit of love! I’m sure someone with more Java experience will be along to give you a proper answer!

Comment: @MattSaunders: Okay, Thank you for your ideas Matt. Let's wait for others opinions.

Comment: But as a primarily Node / TypeScript guy, I have found I was creating extra work for myself by converting table names when this wasn’t really necessary. TBH I’m using GQL wherever I can now, which simplifies things

Comment: @MattSaunders: I understand. Thank for the opinion.

Comment: I really don't get your question. You're in control of everything here, you won't interface with any 3rd party application, so what do you care about RESTfulness to begin with? All you have to do is establish a global naming convention to be followed by anyone accessing your DB, or is there a catch somewhere?